# How to group GraphQL query objects into namespaces?

Tags: javascript, graphql

How can I group my queries into namespaces in GraphQL? I have something like this right now:

```
const queryType = new g.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Query",
    fields: fields,
});
```

and in `fields` I have field -> object mappings and it works fine, but I'd like to group these mappings into two groups (`live` and `historical`). If I modify the above code to this however:

```
const queryType = new g.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Query",
    fields: {
        historical: {
            type: new g.GraphQLObjectType({
                name: "historical",
                fields: fields,
            })
        }
    },
});
```

everything resolves to `null`. How can I write a resolver for this grouping? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Are you looking to resolve Object Types recursively?
For example, say I have `type Person` and the query `{ me: { name father: {name father: { name } }}}`, it should return 3 persons: me, dad, granddad?

Comment: You have not defined a resolver function for `.historical`, and the `rootValue` of your schema doesn't have such a property either. So it's `null`.

Comment: I'm not trying to resolve types recusively, I'd just like to add a namespace to my queries. Can I write a resolver function that would work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

so often people want namespaces for the sake of splitting up code, not sure if this is your end goal but you could achieve that this way aswell:

```
# in one file
type Mutation {
    login(username: String, password: String): User
}

# in other file
extend type Mutation {
    postX(title: String, message: String): X
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem as I'm not using `gql`, but objects, and I'm not using mutations at all.

Comment: doesnt matter if it is an mutation, you can just change type to Query. but if you do not use gql then it is indeed not a solution.